# How update TSL 1.0 to TLS 1.2 version in a Cpanel/WHM server

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

One of our payment team has mentioned us to upgrade the TLs 1.0 version to TLS 1.2 as they are making the security measures. If we haven't updated we will be facing the issues with the payment in our website. Please let us know how this is done from a Cpanel/WHM server.

Thanks

Comment: I have also same issue, have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and found the solution...

In WHM, search for "cPanel Web Services Configuration" located under "Service Configuration".

[image: cPanel Web Services Configuration]

You'll want to add **:!TLSv1** at the end of the protocol string. This forces it to use newer version.

Ideally you'll want to test this on a development server 1st, as it may break your SSL/payment processing if the server is not up to date and cannot use the newer version. There is fallbacks, but it's always best to test 1st!

While you are here as well, you can harden your ciphers. Great tutorial on this can be found here:
https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/

cPanel Official Documentation:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Adjust+Cipher+Protocols

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. Exactly what I needed :)

"WHM(cPanel) --> Service Configuration --> cPanel Web Services Configuration"

To make life easier on the next guy...
The following settings should pass compliancy:

(Cipher List):
HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!AES128

(TLS/SSL Protocols):
SSLv23:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!TLSv11

This will only allow TLSv1.2 connections with the strongest ciphers.
Don't forget to restart cpanel services after making the changes.

Where would we be without our compliance officers keeping the internet safe ;}